# How to package conda env into one single file?

Tags: python, conda

There are anaconda, fully package conda env.
and mini conda, with minium packagea.

Instead of exporting into yaml file or txt file,
would like to export current env.
into a bash executable sh file.

So, this file can be used to install env.
for air gap environnments.

Comment: Hypothetically, if you preload the cached tarballs (*.tar.bz2) into the `miniconda3/pkgs` folder, then installing the env from the .yaml shouldn't hit the internet.  Another option might be to create a local channel and make a .yaml that points to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd look into using conda-pack: https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

It's used to ship a python environment in distributed environments like YARN, where a consistent Python environment is needed across many compute nodes.

You'll develop your environment in a space where internet access is possible and install the conda-pack, then pack it up as an archive eg: `conda pack -n my_env -o out_name.tar.gz`, and deploy it from the archive.  Once you've unzipped the archive you need to source an activate script and it should be good to go. this will look something like: `source <env_directory>/bin/activate`

One thing it can't do is ship a windows environment to a Linux one and vice versa. see the docs linked for more details and caveats.